# Difference of two projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have two projection matrices $P_S$ and $P_Q$ that project onto subspaces $S$ and $Q$ with dimension $s$ and $q$ respectively. Now, if $P_S - P_Q$ is non negative definite and so using the trace we get $s$ is greater than or equal to $q$. Can we somehow get to that $Q$ is a subset of $S$ from there?

Comment: Do you want that $Q \subset S$?

Comment: Yes, I sent this from my phone and I was having difficulty with the tex.

Comment: Ok. I edited your question, please have a look.

Comment: Sorry, I got there with contradiction. I have been trying to get there with a direct proof most the afternoon. It was an exam question and I thought I had it, but didn't. Everyone did contradiction or contra positive and tried going direct but got stuck at s being greater or equal to q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done. Assume not, then have a nonzero $v\in Q$ and $v \notin S$. Write $v = v_1 + v_2$, where $v_1 \in S$ and $v_2 \in S^\perp$. Then

$$\langle(P_S - P_Q) v , v\rangle = \langle P_S (v_1 + v_2) - P_Q (v) , v\rangle = \langle v_1 - (v_1+ v_2) , v\rangle = -||v_2||^2 < 0$$

as $v_2 \neq 0$. Thus $P_S - P_Q$ is not nonnegative definite and that's contradiction.